# Moving an undecorated stage in javafx 2

Tags: javafx-2, stage

I've been trying to move an undecorated stage around the screen, by using the following mouse listeners:

- onPressed
- onReleased
- onDragged

These events are from a rectangle. My idea is to move the undecorated window clicking on the rectangle and dragging all the window.

```
@FXML
protected void onRectanglePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    X = primaryStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
    Y = primaryStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
}

@FXML
protected void onRectangleReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX());
    primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY());
}

@FXML
protected void onRectangleDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + X);
    primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + Y);
}
```

All that I've got with these events is when I press the rectangle and start to drag the window, it moves a little bit. But, when I release the button, the window is moved to where the rectangle is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to handle the event onRectangleReleased.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I created a [sample](https://gist.github.com/2658491) of an animated clock in an undecorated window which you can drag around.

Relevant code from the sample is:

```
// allow the clock background to be used to drag the clock around.
final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
layout.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
    dragDelta.x = stage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
    dragDelta.y = stage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
  }
});
layout.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
    stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
  }
});

...

// records relative x and y co-ordinates.
class Delta { double x, y; }
```

Code looks pretty similar to yours, so not quite sure why your code is not working for you.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty the same. finally found the solution, my mistake was using the wrong event. I was using scene builder. But implementing the setOnMouseDragged, everything goes perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I've noticed that this method has a lower refresh rate than the system window drag. Wish I knew how to use the system window position relocator.

Comment: setting stage to undecorated removes window 10 support for quick edge resizing

Comment: @PathToLife https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455059/allow-user-to-resize-an-undecorated-stage

Answer (score 14):

I'm using this solution for dragging undecoraqted stages by dragging any contained node.

```
private void addDraggableNode(final Node node) {

    node.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            if (me.getButton() != MouseButton.MIDDLE) {
                initialX = me.getSceneX();
                initialY = me.getSceneY();
            }
        }
    });

    node.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            if (me.getButton() != MouseButton.MIDDLE) {
                node.getScene().getWindow().setX(me.getScreenX() - initialX);
                node.getScene().getWindow().setY(me.getScreenY() - initialY);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on jewelsea's reply i made two lamba expressions to set the MouseListeners directly on the scene in my start() method. Works fine :)

```
private double xOffset;
private double yOffset;
         /*
        The two following lambda expressions makes it possible to move the application without the standard StageStyle
         */
        //Lambda mouse event handler
        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            xOffset = primaryStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
            yOffset = primaryStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
        });
        //Lambda mouse event handler
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
            primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
        });enter code here
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your:

```
onRectangleReleased()
```

is passing the very same coordinates from your

```
onRectanglePressed()
```

This happens because as stated in the documentation the getX() method from the MouseEvent class returns

> Horizontal position of the event relative to the origin of the
>   MouseEvent's source.

then, when you release your mouse it actually puts your rectangle in the place it was when you first mouse pressed.

BTW, I use a StackPane with a Rectangle inside and then apply the following code:

```
private void addDragListeners(final Node n){
       n.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                if(me.getButton()!=MouseButton.MIDDLE)
                {
                    initialX = me.getSceneX();
                    initialY = me.getSceneY();
                }
                else
                {
                    n.getScene().getWindow().centerOnScreen();
                    initialX = n.getScene().getWindow().getX();
                    initialY = n.getScene().getWindow().getY();
                }

            }
       });

       n.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                if(me.getButton()!=MouseButton.MIDDLE)
                {
                    n.getScene().getWindow().setX( me.getScreenX() - initialX );
                    n.getScene().getWindow().setY( me.getScreenY() - initialY);
                }
            }
        });
}

addDragListeners(mainStackPane);
```

Besides that, I use the Middle Mouse Button to center my Window on the screen. I hoped it helped. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I was creating the GUI with the scene builder, and I was using the wrong drag event. I implement onMouseDragged and all works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
double x, y;

private void addDragListeners(final Node n, Stage primaryStage){

    n.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent mouseEvent) -> {
        this.x = n.getScene().getWindow().getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
        this.y = n.getScene().getWindow().getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
    });

    n.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent mouseEvent) -> {
        primaryStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + this.x);
        primaryStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + this.y);
    });
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    try {

        ...

        addDragListeners(mainPane, primaryStage);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}
```