# How to set the ellipsis string to an empty string if it is the only text displayed in a JavaFX Label

Tags: javafx, label

I'm trying to keep the Elipsis String (...) on my Label (lbl) but I want it to be set to an empty String when the window gets too small. I'm using the code here to show an example. I'm using the ResizeHelper class found here: [Allow user to resize an undecorated Stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455059/allow-user-to-resize-an-undecorated-stage).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

/**
 *
 * @author bparmeter
 */
public class NewFXMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.setText("Hello World");
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        root.getChildren().add(lbl);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.show();
        ResizeHelper.addResizeListener(primaryStage);

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but it works...

```
    lbl.widthProperty().addListener((ov, o, n) -> {
        final Text t = new Text(lbl.getText().charAt(0)+"...");
        t.applyCss(); 
        final double width = t.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        lbl.setEllipsisString(width>=lbl.getWidth() ? "" : "...");
    });
```