# JavaFX custom titlebar

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create an application which uses the titlebar of a frame like
Firefox does (space on top is used, except the 3 standard-buttons).

Is there any way I could archive this with JavaFX ?

Thank you already!

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874664/javafx-entirely-customized-windows)  what you are looking for ?

Comment: It is somehow what I am looking for, but is there a way how I can use the standard control-buttons of the OS and just customize the rest ?

Comment: like firefox and whatsapp(at least on mac) do

Answer (score 1):

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Set your stage without platform decorations, then create your own HBox for your buttons etc...

then use this answer to allow your app to move around:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780115/moving-an-undecorated-stage-in-javafx-2

Comment: Do you know a way to use the standard native Buttons from the OS and just customize the rest? Like whatsapp(on mac), firefox and chrome do?