# Custom title bar in Javafx 2.0?

Tags: javafx-2

Is there any tutorial on how to create custom title bar in javafx 2.0? I am creating a desktop GUI app and want to have a black gradient title bar with custom buttons for minimizing and closing. [Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/121576-c#-wpf-custom-title-bar-tutorial/) is the tutorial for WPF. I am looking for something similar for javafx

Comment: Title bar of what ? of the frame ? and Custom in which way ? only change the text, or change the color/shape/other ?

Comment: sorry for incomplete question.

Answer (score 6):

To hide platform window:

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Now you can create your own titlebar/window-buttons & style them.

Finally, check "Ensemble" from Oracle JavaFX samples, they've done the exact thing:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to modify the title bar directly. One of the solution could be to remove the platform decorations and add your custom "title bar" to the top of your windows. Here for an example : [JavaFX primaryStage remove windows borders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861178/javafx-primarystage-remove-windows-borders)

Comment: that's a good example. How would I make window move around when user click on the status bar and drag the window around (just like original title bar)?

Comment: A little search around can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780115/moving-an-undecorated-stage-in-javafx-2 :)

Comment: setting stage to undecorated removes window 10 support for quick edge resizing