# JavaFX CSS Remove blue border from window

Tags: java, css, javafx

This blue appears around the edges of a window whenever that window has focus, and I want to get rid of it/style it another color.

[image]

Doing some research, it seems that the following code is the agreed upon solution for *other* nodes, but does not appear to work on the window as a whole.

```
.root{
    -fx-focus-color: transparent !important;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `.root` with `.*`? I suspect the window style is a parent of the 'root' element, hence why it isn't applied to the window. Using the star-selector/wildcard, it will select all elements.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately `*` seems to work on everything except the outside of the window. I'm starting to think that it might be impossible if even the wildcard didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this color is the accent color of Windows 10, and has nothing to do with JavaFX. Oh well, guess it will have to stay.

Comment: One far stretched alternative is using a borderless window and implement the window utility yourself (i.e. resizing, closing, minimizing, maximizing). That way you have full layout control. But again, far stretched.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with this code on your `start` method:

```
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

But the inconveniant this solution, is that remove all windows decoration, top menu bar too.

But you can add it again after deletion.

Code example:

```
package javafxdemo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class JavaDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class WindowButtons extends HBox {

        public WindowButtons() {
            Button closeBtn = new Button("X");

            closeBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    Platform.exit();
                }
            });

            this.getChildren().add(closeBtn);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //remove window decoration
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");

        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();

        int height = 25;
        toolBar.setPrefHeight(height);
        toolBar.setMinHeight(height);
        toolBar.setMaxHeight(height);
        toolBar.getItems().add(new WindowButtons());

        borderPane.setTop(toolBar);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864496/15186569