# How can I set color of stage title bar?

Tags: javafx, colors, titlebar

I wanna change the color of title bar in stage, JAVAFX.
how can i do it?

[image: no white title bar]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SceneBuilder for creating your scene? If so you can set background color using '`-fx-background-color:white`' for your anchorpane or your container that you have selected.

It can also work if you set color for the main container of your stage. using set background. 
`YourContainerName.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white ;");`

Comment: actually I don't want to change background color. I want to change TITLE BAR of STAGE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12875070/12624078 this link might give you some general idea..its going to be a little complicated since changing the title isn't totally a JavaFX feature. You can also take a look at this --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864496/12624078

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is no built in method to do it, my best suggestion would be ditching the native application bar by setting the stage style to undecorated or transparent, and building your title bar from scratch and style it as you please, note that your stage will lose native functionalities like dragging to move or resizing so you'll have to re-implement them if they're important for your stage.